# Adding CSS into a ReactJS Project

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'm using the tutorial here as a base, but I haven't any examples of how to import css files into an app. I've found bits and pieces but not enough to know how to do it. I've added "import styles from './styles/main.css';" into App.jsx and my webpack config is below.

```
var css = require("css!./main.css");

var config = {
    entry: './main.js',

    output: {
        path:'./',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },

    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',

                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style!css!"
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config;`
```

I get the error:

> ./styles/main.css
>   Module parse failed: C:\Projects\reactApp\styles\main.css Unexpected token (1:5)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:5)

That file only has `div {}` right now.

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack config you only need to add [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader) and [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) (you need to `npm install` it first):

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
```

Then you can require the CSS in your `.js` files (components):

```
require('./styles/main.css');
```

Comment: Now I can't start the server. This is my package json: {
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Site with YouTube playlist display",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "youtube",
    "playlist"
  ],
  "author": "Troy Taylor",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
 "style-loader": "^0.13.0"
  }
}

Comment: npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

Comment: npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs reactapp

Comment: Did you require style-loader and css-loader in the webpack config?

Comment: I have them both in "devDependencies".

Comment: How do I do that? Isn't that what the top require does?

Comment: When you remove the loader it works again? You're on Windows?

Comment: Yes and yes. I have to remove the top line "var css = require("css!./main.css");" for it to start.

Comment: Could you try with `require("./main.css");` and without `var css =`?